# Proving Lemmas in Gaussian Distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, marginal-distribution

I am struggling to prove the following lemmas:
[image: The lemmas I want to prove]

How would you suggest me to solve it?

Comment: Are you familiar with the relations between joint density, conditional density and marginal density? For example, in Lemma 2, to get the marginals you just have to integrate the given joint density with respect to the other variable, etc.

Comment: For example, $f_{(X,Y)}(x,y)=f_{Y|X}(y|x)\cdot f_X(x)$?

Comment: @GReyes yes however I am struggling with the computations of it. I can't seem to get far